# ExactTarget Query Data Extension for NUMBER of emails NOT OPENED

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, dataextensions, sql

I am trying to build a Data Extension with subscribers that have NOT OPENED a NUMBER of emails. For example: "RETRIEVE SUBSCRIBERS WHO HAVE NOT OPENED THE LAST 100 EMAILS SENT".

I hope someone can help me build this query.

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt anyone will. Let us see what you have tried

Comment: Hi, the Unengaged Subscribers Report provided me with the desired results without the need of an SQL Query;

Comment: @egalvanlima This report doesn't include Subscriber Key as a column.  How did you add subscriberkey to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work and speed up processing time:

```
select 

SubscriberKey as 'SubscriberKey'

From [Data_Extension]

WHERE SubscriberKey 

NOT IN (
SELECT 

SubscriberKey 
FROM _Open 

WHERE EventDate > dateadd(Day,-100,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do, is not possible, as you are, in a way, querying for data that does not exist. There are three tables that are of interest to you here:

- _Subscriber (stores all you have ever sent to)
- _Sent (stores the individual logs of the emails sent)
- _Open (stores the opens related to the individual sends)

Now, unless you are always sending all email, to all subscribers, sometimes you will have a subscriber that has not been sent a particular email. That means - his "last 100 emails", isn't the same as my "last 100 emails".

The one route you could pursue is manually typing in the email id's for the last 100 emails sent, but that is extremely tedious.

What is typically done here, is a query for those who have been sent an email within the last X period, but haven't opened or clicked the email (remember, due to the way tracking works, sometimes you can click an email without it registering as an open). A query to achieve this, can look like this:

```
SELECT 
s.SubscriberKey AS SubscriberKey, 
sub.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress

FROM _Sent s

LEFT JOIN _Subscribers sub
ON s.SubscriberKey = sub.SubscriberKey

WHERE 
s.EventDate > DateAdd(Day,-100,GetDate())

AND NOT EXISTS (
  Select 1 
  FROM _Open o 
  WHERE s.JobId = o.JobId 
  AND s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
  )

AND NOT EXISTS (
  Select 1 
  FROM _Click c 
  WHERE s.JobId = c.JobId 
  AND s.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
  )
```

This will see if a subscriber has opened any of the email it was sent within the last 100 days. NOW - **THIS IS A LOT OF DATA** - and sometimes this can time out, meaning that you might need to pull the sent data, open data and click data into separate data extensions first - and then instead of querying and comparing system views, you are querying and comparing data extensions which will typically perform better.

Comment: Hi @kenneth-wagner , is your query giving subscribers who have no opened any email in past 100 days OR is it giving subscribers who have not opened last 100 emails as mentioned by egalvanlima in the original question above?

Comment: Just following up? This query is not returning anything.